# Какие версии у CLR в платформах .Net Core и .Net 5?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Не могу что-то сориентироваться в современных версиях CLR

.Net Framework 2 - 3.5 это CLR 2

.Net Framework 4 - 4.8 это CLR 4

В какой версии CLR исполняется код .Net Core 1, 2, 3, и .Net5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET Core версия CLR одинакова с версией самого .NET Core. Обновления CLR выпускаются вместе с обновлениями стандартной библиотеки. Если говорить о свойстве Environment.Version, то до версии 3.0 оно возвращало фальшивое значение `4.0.30319.42000` в целях обратной совместимости. Начиная с 3.0 оно [возвращает реальную версию .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26833), например 3.1.x для .NET Core 3.1. Технически берется версия NuGet-пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App из файла .deps.json.

Версия сборки в метаданных (директива .assembly в IL) для некоторых стандартных библиотек остается 4.0, видимо, также для обратной совместимости, так как эта версия используется для разрешения зависимостей с использованием строго имени. Версия файла для некоторых DLL, которая отображается в свойствах файла в проводнике, также в основном осталась 4.x, но это значение вообще ни на что не влияет.

Answer (score 2):

.Net Core 1, 2, 3, и .Net5, все используют CoreCLR.

> .NET Core and .NET 5+ releases have a single product version, that is, there is no separate CLR version.
> [CLR versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr)

также:
[Introducing .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/)